# How to send a message using iChat and AppleScript

Tags: scripting, applescript, ichat

I have a need to send a message to a number of people to let them know when an event is occurring. It is always the same list of people, and always the same event, so I would like to script it.

The problem that I have is that I know that I need to use the *send* command to send the message. And the format of that command is

```
tell application iChat to send "message" to _buddy_
```

The problem is how to get that buddy. I know how to get the list of all buddies, and to loop over them:

```
tell application "iChat"
    repeat with myBuddy in buddies
    end repeat
end tell
```

What I can't seem to find is how to just get the buddies that I care about, for example those with name "Pietje Piet" and "Joe Anonymous", and then just to send messages to these two contacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to aquire a list of the buddies you care about in a separate list somehow. Here's a suggestion:

```
set peopleICareAbout to {"Pietje Piet", "Joe Anonymous"}

tell application "iChat"
    repeat with myBuddy in buddies
        --get properties of myBuddy
        if full name of myBuddy is in peopleICareAbout then
            send "dfgdgdf gdg dfg dfg" to myBuddy
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: That does exactly what I want! Although I had to change the message of course ;-)

Comment: This works great on OS X Yosemite, just need to change the application to "Messages".