# Send group iMessage using applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, message, imessage, osascript

Does anyone know how to send a group message using applescript/osascript? I've tried a bunch of stuff but nothing seems to work.

Comment: That's a different question. He's sending a message to multiple individual people. I want to send a group message.

Comment: By `group message` do you mean a group that you've defined in your contacts, or where exactly?

Answer (score 2):

[image: From iMessages dictionary]

If you take a look into the iMessages (former iChat) dictionary you see that you only can send messages to a `buddy` or a `text chat`. There is no "group" available. BUT, if you have a group, say a list of people, you can compare this to available `buddies` and send to each one of them, like suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325150/how-to-send-a-message-using-ichat-and-applescript).

Answer (score 1):

@turingtested's response above led me to a solution that solved this problem for me, provided that there's an already-existing named chat.

In AppleScript's documentation, `send` can send to a `chat`:

[image: AppleScript send documentation]

A `chat` has a `name` property that is how the chat's name appears in the chat list:

[image: AppleScript chat documentation]

I then went into Messages, created the desired group and added a group name.

To add a group name in Messages.app on macOS, right click on the group, select **Details…**, click on **Change Group Name and Photo**, and edit the group name as desired.

Once you've done that, the following code will do the trick:

```
tell application "Messages"
    send "Your message here" to chat "group name"
end tell
```