# Applescript won't send iMessage

Tags: sms, applescript, imessage

I am trying to send a message to myself from my computer, but it won't send! Any advice? Here is the script I have:

```
tell application "Messages"
    set theBuddy to buddy "##########" of service "Contacts"    
    send "Hello" to theBuddy
end tell
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325150/how-to-send-a-message-using-ichat-and-applescript (just replace "iChat" with "Messages")