# Sending iMessage from Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, message, imessage, ichat

Is it possible for a Mac app to invoke the Messages app to send a message to a particular contact or phone number? The only plausible lead I'm found was the IMService framework, but that seems to be deprecated in 10.9 Mavericks.

Comment: Have you investigated an AppleScript solution? Message might expose some kind of AS interface

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to use [Apple Script](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) to send messages via the Messages application.

See this question for an example:
[How to send a message using iChat and AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325150/how-to-send-a-message-using-ichat-and-applescript)

Comment: Thanks. The script works by itself, but not when invoked from another app using NSAppleScript. I get a message in the console: "error while executing script. Error {
    NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = Messages;
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "A privilege violation occurred.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Messages got an error: A privilege violation occurred.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-10004";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {110, 41}";
}"

Comment: Is your app sandboxed?

Comment: This error is described in detail here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_6/RN-10_6.html

Comment: It is sandboxed. I have followed some instructions on adding the relevant entitlements, but it still doesn't work. In particular, in com.apple.security.scripting-targets, I added: 
 <key>com.apple.iChat</key>
 <string>com.apple.ichat.applescript</string>